# How to reduce the RequestCharge to 1RUs while reading data from query in azure cosmos DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

[image]
[image]

I want to make that 2.28RUs to 1RUs by changing my query,can anyone help me out?

Comment: do you have a partition?

Comment: @SteveDrake This particular issue isn't related to partitioning. The OP is creating a query (vs a direct read), which has additional RU cost overhead, even with a single-partition collection.

Comment: `ReadDocumentAsync` requires a partition hence my question :) well ok, maybe that didn't jump to mind :) but I am aware that querying over partitions will cost more RUs so I do feel that my Q was valid. If the OP had answered `YES` to a partition my advice would be to have a way to lookup the partition key, if the OP had said `NO` then your answer is perfect (I did upvote it btw). I have a system that has this requirement, we have another root to find the partition.

Comment: That's fair. Just meant that, regardless of partitioning, OP was not going to be able to reduce the RU cost of a query (by anything significant) vs a point read.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot magically make a query cost 1 RU. I'm pretty sure you *won't* be able to, as you're utilizing the query engine. You might be able to reduce RU a bit by just returning the properties you need (vs returning `*`).

You can reduce RU a bit at *write time* by excluding properties from being indexed, when you know you won't be searching by those properties.

But to reduce RU cost during retrieval, you'll need to do a direct read, vs a query. This requires an API/SDK call, and cannot be executed via the query explorer. In c#, this would look something like;

```cs
var response = 
  await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(dbId, collectionId, docId));
```

You can then inspect `response.RequestCharge` to see what this cost in RU (and it should be lower than the query cost).